iPhone does not ring even though "Do not disturb" is not active and "Allow notifications" is enabled
My iPhone is working for outbound calls and does properly sound off when searched via "Find my". But calls are not making any sound.  If I happen to be looking at my phone I can see inbound calls and pick them up. They're just silent.
The "Alerts" from Phone are set to "Lock Screen".  I have been assuming that means that the notifications - including ringing! - are enabled even if my phone is locked. That is what we want.
What might be wrong here?

Not sure but I would try going to 'Sounds' and switching ringtones a couple of times to see if it fixes. Otherwise try a hard reset. What is your phone model ?
